# StaticLoggerBinder, Drools, Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, drools

I'm a total novice to executing in the Java environment, Eclipse and Drools.  But I saw the same question from someone else who never got an answer, so I'll post my problem.

I've followed the installation instructions for Drools in Eclipse.  Then tried to run `DroolsTest.Java` and get the following message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:23)
```

The message at the mentioned website suggested adding a .jar (just one of them) to the Classpath.  I had one of them in my Drools 6 Runtime directory, so added it to my classpath.  See below.

Classpath: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\0 TM Stuff\BRE Review\Drools 6 Runtime\slf4j-api.jar

I've done the install on 2 different laptops, Windows 7 and got the same result.

I'm dead in the water now.  Any ideas to get past this situation are greatly appreciated.

Terry

Here is the code.  This is the problem line `kSession.insert(message);`

```
package com.sample;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
```

/**
 * This is a sample class to launch a rule.
 */
    public class DroolsTest {

```
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        // load up the knowledge base
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

        // go !
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setMessage("Hello World");
            message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
            kSession.insert(message);
            kSession.fireAllRules();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Message {

        public static final int HELLO = 0;
        public static final int GOODBYE = 1;

        private String message;

        private int status;

        public String getMessage() {
            return this.message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return this.status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Install the m2e Maven Eclipse plugin to enable Eclipse to configure the dependencies correctly.

To get m2e to update your project, right-click on your project and go to "Maven" -> "Update Project", which should update it and put all of the Drools dependencies on the classpath.

Note that you will also need a logging implementation in your pom.xml if using SLF4J. For instance, I tend to use the Log4J logging implementation as follows:

```
  <!-- The SLF4J API, which you may already have on your classpath, 
       as it looks like Drools imports it. -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- The SLF4J Log4J implementation. This contains the StaticLoggerBinder class. -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I think I have the maven plug-in installed.  When I go to properties, maven, installationS I see "embedded (3.0.4/1.4.9.2013531-2315).

Comment: OK, it works now.  I downloaded Maven, but didn't install it as a plug-in.  The directions I was following didn't say to do that.  Right clicking on the Drools project in the package browser doesn't show Maven and running the application still gives the first 3 lines of my original message, but it kept going and gave me the expected output from the HelloWorld rules.  So thank you for your clues that sent me in the right direction.

Comment: btw ... The alternative way to do it if you have Maven as a standalone command-line app is to `cd` to the root of your project and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. That will generate the Eclipse project properties to configure all the dependencies.

Comment: Looks like I have to go through the tutorial for maven to figure out how it works before I can figure out how Drools work.  Lots of work when all I wanted to do was a quick evaluation of Drools.  I already know that I like Oracle OPA and IBM WODM better as rule management environments, so I'm hoping that there is something spectacular lurking in Drools to make it worth this effort. I know, I'm being bitchy, but this has all been very frustrating.

Comment: To be honest, being able to use Maven or Gradle (or both!) is pretty much fundamental to any Java application development. I find it understandable that the Drools documentation makes the assumption that you should know how it works. And all you need to know is a handful of commands. Using Maven makes Drools massively more manageable than the competition when it comes to making changes and deploying them. Admittedly, the Drools tooling is not as pretty to look at as WebSphere. However, there is the fact that Drools is much simpler to set up and customise. And it doesn't cost anything...

Answer (score 0):

You should have these two jar files in your classpath (/extra is my local root for stuff):

```
 /extra/slf4j-1.7.5/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar:/extra/slf4j-1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
```

But the message about the missing logger should not cause the NPE, so probably there's something else in your DroolsTest.java. Show the source, please.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but no difference.  The code is the sample that is created when you create a new Drools project.  Pasted below.

Comment: Code is too long to paste.  Is there a way to attach a file? I see that it is possible to include a URL, but didn't see how to attach file.

Comment: @Inastrol Add it to your question, not as a comment.